# kendo-ui-angular2 grid detail "+" click event

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

How to tap in to the click event of the "+" expand "-" collapse click events.
Clicking on the row triggers the "cellClickHandler($event)", I need it to be able to handle detail click as an event also.

```
<kendo-grid
    [data]="mainData"
    (cellClick)="cellClickHandler($event)"
>
  <kendo-grid-column>
    // column stuff
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column>
    // more column stuff
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <ng-template kendoGridDetailTemplate>
    <table>
      // stuff
    </table>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `detailCollapse` and `detailExpand` events from the `kendo-grid` component.

**Example** ([Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/cLf66en0G4xbVYw65BtY/))

```
<kendo-grid
    ...
    (detailCollapse)="collapseHandler($event)"
    (detailExpand)="expandHandler($event)"
>
    ...
</kendo-grid>
```

Detailed information on all available events can be found in the [Grid API](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-events) section.